# Nested Case in SQL 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-server-2000

I have the following SQL statement, when executing it on SQL 2008 it works perfectly with no problem. But when excuted in SQL 2000 it says:

> Internal SQL Server error

I think the problem comes because of using nested case statement in SQL 2000. Here is the SQL statement:

```
 WHEN 14 THEN
                  Case When  (select COUNT(*) from [dbo].[mnrFnBI_Fixed](@CurrencyID) f where f.BAccCustID!=0x0 AND f.biMatID = bi.biMatID)>0 THEN

                    CASE  (select top 1 PriceType from  (select top 1 f.BDate,f.BNumber , tc.PriceType From [dbo].[mnrFnBI_Fixed](@CurrencyID) f  inner join #tcust tc on tc.AccID = f.BAccCustID AND tc.PriceType!=0 Where   f.biMatID =bi.biMatID AND f.BAccCustID != 0x0 order by f.BDate desc,f.BNumber  desc ) as k)  -- Price From customer Card 
                            WHEN 1 THEN 
                            CASE @UseUnit WHEN 1 THEN mtEndUser1 
                                    WHEN 2 THEN mtEndUser2  
                                    WHEN 3 THEN mtEndUser3  
                                    WHEN 4 THEN mtEndUser4  
                                    WHEN 5 THEN mtEndUser5  
                                    WHEN 0 THEN CASE [mtDefUnit]    WHEN 1 THEN mtEndUser1 
                                                    WHEN 2 THEN mtEndUser2  
                                                    WHEN 3 THEN mtEndUser3  
                                                    WHEN 4 THEN mtEndUser4  
                                                    WHEN 5 THEN mtEndUser5  
                                                END
                                    END
            ---*******************---
                            WHEN 2 THEN 
                            CASE @UseUnit WHEN 1 THEN  mtWhole1 
                                    WHEN 2 THEN mtWhole2 
                                    WHEN 3 THEN mtWhole3  
                                    WHEN 4 THEN mtWhole4  
                                    WHEN 5 THEN mtWhole5 
                                        WHEN 0 THEN CASE [mtDefUnit] WHEN 1 THEN mtWhole1 
                                                                WHEN 2 THEN mtWhole2  
                                                                WHEN 3 THEN mtWhole3 
                                                                WHEN 4 THEN mtWhole4  
                                                                WHEN 5 THEN mtWhole5 
                                                            END
                                        END 

                    ---*******************---           

                    END 
                    END
```

When I remove the part between the '*****' it works perfectly !

Please tell me how case statement works with SQL 2000 ?!

**Update :** 
when change the above code to :

```
 WHEN 14 THEN
                  Case  
                            WHEN (select COUNT(*) from [dbo].[mnrFnBI_Fixed](@CurrencyID) f where f.BAccCustID!=0x0 AND f.biMatID = bi.biMatID)>0 THEN

                case 
                when (select top 1 PriceType from  (select top 1 f.BDate,f.BNumber , tc.PriceType From [dbo].[mnrFnBI_Fixed](@CurrencyID) f  inner join #tcust tc on tc.AccID = f.BAccCustID AND tc.PriceType!=0 Where   f.biMatID =bi.biMatID AND f.BAccCustID != 0x0 order by f.BDate desc,f.BNumber  desc ) as k) =1 THEN 
                        CASE @UseUnit WHEN 1 THEN mtEndUser1 
                                WHEN 2 THEN mtEndUser2  
                                WHEN 3 THEN mtEndUser3  
                                WHEN 4 THEN mtEndUser4  
                                WHEN 5 THEN mtEndUser5  
                                WHEN 0 THEN CASE [mtDefUnit]    WHEN 1 THEN mtEndUser1 
                                                WHEN 2 THEN mtEndUser2  
                                                WHEN 3 THEN mtEndUser3  
                                                WHEN 4 THEN mtEndUser4  
                                                WHEN 5 THEN mtEndUser5  
                                            END
                                END


                when(select top 1 PriceType from  (select top 1 f.BDate,f.BNumber , tc.PriceType From [dbo].[mnrFnBI_Fixed](@CurrencyID) f  inner join #tcust tc on tc.AccID = f.BAccCustID AND tc.PriceType!=0 Where   f.biMatID =bi.biMatID AND f.BAccCustID != 0x0 order by f.BDate desc,f.BNumber  desc ) as k) = 2 THEN 
                        CASE @UseUnit WHEN 1 THEN  mtWhole1 
                                WHEN 2 THEN mtWhole2 
                                WHEN 3 THEN mtWhole3  
                                WHEN 4 THEN mtWhole4  
                                WHEN 5 THEN mtWhole5 
                                    WHEN 0 THEN CASE [mtDefUnit] WHEN 1 THEN mtWhole1 
                                                            WHEN 2 THEN mtWhole2  
                                                            WHEN 3 THEN mtWhole3 
                                                            WHEN 4 THEN mtWhole4  
                                                            WHEN 5 THEN mtWhole5 
                                                        END
                                    END 


                END 
                END
```

it works , so please tell what's wrong with the first Sql Commands in sql 2000 ?!

Comment: You might want to consider `COALESCE(NULLIF(@UseUnit,0),mtDefUnit)` to reduce the amount of nesting/repetition (of course, if you can change your setup so that a `NULL` `@UseUnit` represents the "fall back to default" option then you can eliminate the `NULLIF` above)

Comment: thanks for the tip , i noticed that when i remove the second select and replace it with other condition then it works ! so it could be caused by the second select statement

Answer (score 0):

This example can Help You.

```
UPDATE table_name 
  SET column_name=CASE 
WHEN column_name in ('value1', 'value2',.....) 
  THEN 'update_value' 
WHEN column_name in ('value1', 'value2',.....) 
  THEN 'update_value' 
END
```